# Disable postman download popup

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

I use postman collection runner to test that my services are up.

I have a POST request that return a pdf file.

When it comes to that request, I have a popup asking to download the pdf file.

For testing that my request is ok, I just need the return code 200. I want to disable this download popup.

Do you know how to do that?

PS: I am using postman chrome app.